# How do I add pagination to a Flask API and retrieve it by using Retrofit?

Tags: android, flask, pagination, retrofit2

My app makes API calls through Retrofit's API service, and the API is built in Python using Flask. At the moment, no pagination is implemented and all items of the JSON response array are retrieved in a one time call. How do I modify my methods in Flask to add pagination? I would like to have a limit of two items per page, if possible.

API route:

```
curated_section = Blueprint('curated_section', __name__)

@curated_section.route('/sections', methods=['GET'])
def get_active_curated_sections():
    """ get all active curated sections """
```

This is the repository:

```
def get_active_curated_sections():
    rows = database.func('community.get_active_curated_sections', [])
    if len(rows) <= 0:
        return []
    curated_sections = [CuratedSection.map_from_row(row) for row in rows]
    return curated_sections
```

This is the controller:

```
def get_active_curated_sections():
    curated_sections = curated_section_repository.get_active_curated_sections()
    if curated_sections is None:
        abort(404, {'message': 'No curated sections found'})
    return jsonify([curated_section.get_serialized() for curated_section in curated_sections])
```

In my android app, this is how I've constructed the API service:

```
public class MyAPI {
    public interface APIService {
        @GET("sections")
        Call<JsonArray> getCuratedSections(
            @Header("Authorization") String authorization)
        );
    }

    public static APIService endpoint() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        APIService apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        return apiService;
    }
}
```